# Merge two .au files to a single .au file using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg and I went through the documentation it, but was not able to get the most out of it.
I also searched for the same on stackoverflow but could not find exactly what i want.
I need the following things to be done using ffmpeg.
inputs: file1.au, file2.au
outputs: demo.au

1. Merge two .au files to single demo.au file.
2. I need the output file's duration to be that of the longest file.
3. I need to merge the audio files at a specific duration i.e. file2.au should be merged with file1.au from 5th second of file1.au (if this is possible)

I need the seperate answers for all the tasks if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the answer for the 1st and 2nd question.  
the following command will help to achieve it.  
`ffmpeg  -i file1.au -i file2.au -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest demo.au`  

where inputs=2 displays the total input files.

Comment: You can provide answers to your own question instead of just a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the information. @LordNeckbeard, I will take that into consideration from next time.